# PHP passing variable in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function like this

```
function login_redirect($redirect, $vars = array())
{
    return $redirect;
}
```

I would like to pass this variable in that array

```
$user = null
```

I tried like this

```
function login_redirect($redirect, $vars = array($user => null))
{
    return $redirect;
}
```

But I'm getting error. Can anyone correct me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the array key incorrectly. The following works:

```
function login_redirect($redirect, $vars = array('user' => null))
{
    return $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is what you're trying to do:

```
function login_redirect($redirect, $vars = array())
{
    return $redirect;
}

// Redirect:
login_redirect("somepath", array("user" => $user));
```

Now the array you pass to `login_redirect` will contain the value of `$user`

Comment: Now I'm guessing this isn't what you're trying to do at all. I'll just stay here in the corner and try not to attract attention

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ThiefMaster's code working correctly.